# Как улучшить качество фотографии?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, обработка-изображений

Тут во время спора пришла неплохая идейка - научиться улучшать качаство фотографий. Но есть прям малюсенькая проблема - никогда не работал в python с изображениями и нейронками.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается, про какие библиотеки надо почитать, да и вообще на сколько это сложно и муторно?

Если честно, то хотелось бы вот прямо с нуля это сделать и написать свою библиотеку, если есть такие статьи, то обязательно кидайте)

### PS

Такс, дополняю вопрос и объясняюсь более корректно и конкретно.

Есть вот такая фотка:
[image: фото с качеством 7 шакалов из 10]

Хочу чтобы при пропуске её через программу можно было несильно напрягаясь прочитать код на мониторе. Возможно ли это с помощью python и каким образом?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115139/discussion-on-question-by-dgdays----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу чтобы при пропуске её через программу можно было несильно
> напрягаясь прочитать код на мониторе. Возможно ли это с помощью python
> и каким образом?

если по файлу размером 1024 байт вычислить md5 размером 16 байт, то можно ли потом по этой md5 восстановить целый файл?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тут никакой искусственный интеллект не поможет восстановить изображение, если так сильно оно искажено (т.е. высокий уровень потери информации)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чистка изображения ничего не даёт - максимум можно по размеру одной буквы восстановить сколько букв содержится в словах текста, а дальше надо быть аббатом Фариа из Монте Кристо чтобы что-то прочитать

на приведённой фотке мелкие детали потеряны полностью и восстановлению не подлежат никакими алгоритмами.

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается, про какие библиотеки надо
> почитать, да и вообще на сколько это сложно и муторно?

для начала надо будет прочитать учебники "Математический анализ", "Линейная алгебра и Аналитическая геометрия", затем скорее всего и "Тензорный анализ", затем переходить к "Теория чисел" и т.д.

Не существует универсальной формулы улучшения изображения, каждый раз приходится более-менее индивидуально решать подобные задачи, конечно за исключением случаев улучшения "на коленке" - т.е. чуть заблюрить, чуть зашарпить, разбить на каналы и вычистить цвета

Опять же цветокоррекция - это лишь малая часть обработки изображения и как было показано выше - если информация утеряна полностью, вы уже ничего не восстановите

Конечно можно использовать машинное обучение и т.д., но опять - изображение это не восстановит и читать то, что изначально прочитать нельзя вы не сможете, картинка будет улучшена но опять же не очень значительно.

Comment: @DGDays, самый простой алгоритм улучшения читаемости - это увеличение чёткости (фильтр sharp), когда анализируются соседние пиксели каждого пикселя, но опять же работать надо не с RGB-изображениями, а хотя бы c YUV (большая часть информации в Y канале сидит) и т.д.

Comment: @DGDays, к примеру - https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs448f/lectures/2.1/Sharpening.pdf